# "UnresolvedAddressException" - Confluent kafka server start

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I have downloaded confluent kafka in windows machine. Zookeeper is running successfully while running kafka server i am getting below exception.

```
INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/<unresolved>:2181. Will not attempt to 
authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
WARN Session 0x0 for server localhost/<unresolved>:2181, unexpected error, closing socket 
connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:149)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:157)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkRemote(SocketChannelImpl.java:815)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:837)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.registerAndConnect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:277)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.connect(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:287)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1021)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1064)
```

Below options i tried to solve the issue but it didn't work.

1.Added listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092,advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
in server.properties file

2.Added localhost ip address in hosts file

Below are properties in server.properties file

```
  num.network.threads=3
  num.io.threads=8
  socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
  socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
  socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
  log.dirs=C:\KafkaLog
  num.partitions=1
  num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
  offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
  transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
  transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
  log.retention.hours=168
  log.segment.bytes=1073741824
  log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
  zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
  zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
  confluent.support.metrics.enable=true
  confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
  group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Zookeeper properties are

```
 dataDir=C:\ZookeeperLog
 clientPort=2181
 maxClientCnxns=0
```

Comment: Don't touch your hosts file. Confluent cli command doesn't support windows, so how are you running it?

Comment: actually i am working on confluent kafka.

Comment: There's no such thing. Confluent Platform is a distribution of Apache Kafka, Apache Zookeeper and other tools. That still didn't answer my question, though. Plus, there's a clear blog on running Kafka on Windows https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/